# seleccion multiple con checkbox con js

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Buen día, le comento estoy realizando una selección múltiple con checkbox con js, he logrado hasta ahora capturar las selecciones que hago y mostrarlas por consola, ahora bien, son 9 checkbox si quisiera controlar las selecciones como por ej: si selecciona 1 y 2 vaya a la página 2 si selecciona la pagina1, vaya a la pagina1.html pero si selecciona la opción 1 y 3 me diga que la opcion no es válida, o si elige la opción 5, 6 vaya a la pagina7.html. Soy nuevo en esto, ¿me podrian ayudar?

```
function capturarSelecciones() {
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("check");
var selecciones = [];
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
selecciones.push(checkboxes[i].value);
}
}
console.log(selecciones);}
```

Comment: Sugiero que incluyas un fragmento de HTML, si no los 9 checkboxes, por lo menos algunos para ir sobre ese código al escribir una respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Si tenes diferentes checkboxes que pueden cumplir diferentes funciones lo que te recomiendo es que lo filtres de acuerdo a algun otro atributo del elemento. Por ejemplo [data-id](https://www.dofactory.com/html/data/id#:%7E:text=The%20id%20attribute%20assigns%20an,support%20the%20element.) puede ser una opcion.

Una vez que tengas el atributo en tus checkboxes podes filtrarlos por este usando la funcion [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Cuando ya puedas obtener los atributos, puedes comparar dependiendo de los valores. De esta manera cada checkbox te va a quedar univocamente identificado.

Decime si se entendio.

Saludos!